# typescript optional indexer type that returns same type

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
export enum KeyCode {
  Alt = 'meta',
  Command = 'command',
  Ctrl = 'ctrl',
  DownArrow = 'down',
  Enter = 'enter',
  Escape = 'esc',
  LeftArrow = 'left',
  Mod = 'mod',
  RightArrow = 'right',
  UpArrow = 'up'
}


export interface ShortcutAction {
  keys: string | string[];
  action: string;
}

export type ShortcutHandler = (action: string, event: KeyboardEvent) => void;

export type KeyStroke = KeyCode | string;

export interface Combination {
  combination: KeyStroke[];
}

export interface Sequence {
  sequence: KeyStroke[];
}

export type ShortcutItem = KeyStroke | KeyStroke[] | Combination | Sequence;

export interface Shortcut {
  [key: string]: ShortcutItem;
}

export type ShortcutMap =
  | {
      [key: string]: Shortcut;
    }
  | Shortcut;

export const buildFromMap = (shortcutMap: ShortcutMap, key?: string ) => {
  const map = key ? shortcutMap[key] : shortcutMap;

  return buildShortcuts(map);
}

export const buildShortcuts = (map: Shortcut): ShortcutAction[] => {
  return [];
}

const singleShortcutMap: ShortcutMap = {
  MOVE_LEFT: [KeyCode.LeftArrow, 'a'],
  MOVE_RIGHT: [KeyCode.RightArrow, 'd']
};

const multipleShortcutMap: ShortcutMap = {
  key1: {
    MOVE_UP: 'a'
  },
  key2: {
    MOVE_UP: 'a'
  }
};

buildFromMap(singleShortcutMap);
buildFromMap(multipleShortcutMap, "key1");
```

I want the `ShortcutMap` type to be able to define the following 2 examples:

```
const singleShortcutMap: ShortcutMap = {
  MOVE_LEFT: [KeyCode.LeftArrow, 'a'],
  MOVE_RIGHT: [KeyCode.RightArrow, 'd']
};

const multipleShortcutMap: ShortcutMap = {
  key1: {
    MOVE_UP: 'a'
  },
  key2: {
    MOVE_UP: 'a'
  }
};
```

So it can optionally have a key that returns `Shortcut` type or it is the `Shortcut` type.

I have tried this:

```
export type ShortcutMap =
  | {
      [key: string]: Shortcut;
    }
  | Shortcut;
```

But it is coming out as:

```
string | {
    [key: string]: Shortcut;
} | Shortcut | string[] | Combination | Sequence
```

So  I don't think I am adequately narrowing the type but I'm not sure how to in this instance.

I have created a [playground to illustrate this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20enum%20KeyCode%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Alt%20%3D%20'meta'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Command%20%3D%20'command'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Ctrl%20%3D%20'ctrl'%2C%0D%0A%20%20DownArrow%20%3D%20'down'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Enter%20%3D%20'enter'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Escape%20%3D%20'esc'%2C%0D%0A%20%20LeftArrow%20%3D%20'left'%2C%0D%0A%20%20Mod%20%3D%20'mod'%2C%0D%0A%20%20RightArrow%20%3D%20'right'%2C%0D%0A%20%20UpArrow%20%3D%20'up'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20ShortcutAction%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20keys%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20action%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ShortcutHandler%20%3D%20(action%3A%20string%2C%20event%3A%20KeyboardEvent)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20KeyStroke%20%3D%20KeyCode%20%7C%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Combination%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20combination%3A%20KeyStroke%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Sequence%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20sequence%3A%20KeyStroke%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ShortcutItem%20%3D%20KeyStroke%20%7C%20KeyStroke%5B%5D%20%7C%20Combination%20%7C%20Sequence%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Shortcut%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20ShortcutItem%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20type%20ShortcutMap%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Shortcut%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7C%20Shortcut%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20buildFromMap%20%3D%20(shortcutMap%3A%20ShortcutMap%2C%20key%3F%3A%20string%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20map%20%3D%20key%20%3F%20shortcutMap%5Bkey%5D%20%3A%20shortcutMap%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20buildShortcuts(map)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20buildShortcuts%20%3D%20(map%3A%20Shortcut)%3A%20ShortcutAction%5B%5D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20singleShortcutMap%3A%20ShortcutMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20MOVE_LEFT%3A%20%5BKeyCode.LeftArrow%2C%20'a'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20MOVE_RIGHT%3A%20%5BKeyCode.RightArrow%2C%20'd'%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20multipleShortcutMap%3A%20ShortcutMap%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20key1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20MOVE_UP%3A%20'a'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20key2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20MOVE_UP%3A%20'a'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AbuildFromMap(singleShortcutMap)%3B%0D%0AbuildFromMap(multipleShortcutMap%2C%20%22key1%22)%3B)